# 'at' command won't open the program

Tags: bash

I have a Python script that opens a VLC player; when I run it from the command line, it works perfectly.

I have a bash function that calls this program with the input of a time, like so:

```
alarm (){
    echo "python /Users/thumbtackthief/Documents/code/steven_alarm/alarm.py" | at ${1:-0800}
}
```

When I call this function, it runs at the appropriate time, but does not actually open the program.  I know it is running because in /var/mail I get a message with any print statements from the functions (not sure why it's outputting to /var/mail; I didn't set that up).  Is there something different I'm supposed to do to actually open the VLC player?  Permissions on player and video are set to 755.

Here is a message in /var/mail:

```
From thumbtackthief@My-iMac.local  Tue Jul  4 09:51:16 2017
Return-Path: <thumbtackthief@My-iMac.local>
X-Original-To: thumbtackthief
Delivered-To: thumbtackthief@My-iMac.local
Received: by My-iMac.local (Postfix, from userid 501)
    id 51B758F818FC; Tue,  4 Jul 2017 09:51:15 -0400 (EDT)
Subject: Output from your job a00017017d429f
Message-Id: <20170704135116.51B758F818FC@My-iMac.local>
Date: Tue,  4 Jul 2017 09:51:15 -0400 (EDT)
From: thumbtackthief@My-iMac.local (Atrun Service)

python /Users/thumbtackthief/Documents/code/steven_alarm/alarm.py
```

Comment: Lots of pertinent details not given. Actual errors emitted would be a place to start -- if your at job no longer had a valid Xauthority ticket or DISPLAY, that would be one unsurprising resolution, but there's not nearly enough information here to know for sure.

Comment: (the text of your Python script? Also potentially pertinent, if only to evaluate the error handling; if you're swallowing exceptions rather than emitting them as text, that's a thing you'll want to fix).

Comment: There are no errors, and yes it runs when manually executed.

Comment: It's a very simple script and I have no error handling in it.

Comment: Why in the world would this get two close votes?!?

Comment: I did not do it, but reason could be someone thought this question is not quite related to programming and much more suited at Unix & Linux StackExchage site

Comment: Ah. You're probably right.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At does not execute under your login-shell.  As for why you are receiving the output via mail: that is normal, see `man at`:

> The user will be mailed standard error and standard output from his 
>   commands, if any. Mail will be sent using the command 
>   /usr/sbin/sendmail. If at is executed from a su(1) shell, the owner of >the login shell will receive the mail.

So, because you're in a different context, the script doesn't know where to display your VLC. Handing out a DISPLAY variable would help, but then the VLC also needs the authority to display there.

And yes, it's probably more a unix/linux thing.

Something to try, if you're in a sufficiently closed environment (this is a cut-and-paste from my environment):

```
[ljm@verlaine ~]$ xhost +
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
[ljm@verlaine ~]$ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
```

The `:0.0` is used in your `at`:

```
[ljm@verlaine ~]$ at 19:30
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> DISPLAY=:0.0 xclock  # 
at> <EOT>
job 6 at Tue Jul  4 19:30:00 2017
```

That displays an xclock at that specific time.

Comment: `at` actually stores active environment variables alongside the job, and restores them for running.

Comment: ...that said, turns out you're right that `DISPLAY` is not passed through (being one of the explicit exceptions). Perhaps you might edit the answer to show how to circumvent that?

Comment: (Also, as a man page extract isn't code, `>` quoting might be more appropriate than code formatting).

Comment: It depends a lot on what system you're on. For Debian-style systems, `xhost` will be in `x11-xserver-utils`. For Redhat/Fedora, it is in `xorg-x11-server-utils`, for AIX, it is in `X11.apps.config` etcetera.

Comment: Just noticed the `iMac` in your mail-headers; Apple does not use X11, so my quick&dirty solution will not work. I'm sorry, but I've no experience with Mac's.